# How to calculate Jmeter Throughput for summary report

Tags: jmeter

[image]

Can anyone help me, how to calculate **Throughput & Std.Dev** in Jmeter summary report.

The formula I have used is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)`

But how to **calculate total time in Summary report**.

Comment: In question title you ask about Throughput, then you ask about Throughput & Std.Dev (but your question shows screenshot of Throughput & Std.Dev already calculated), and then in the end you are asking about total time.  So what are you asking really?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you I have jmeter generated summary report for my application in this report I need to know how to calculate Throughput and std dev .

Answer (score 0):

checkout [SmartMeter.io reports](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-step-5---reporting). It already contains throughput and std. deviation. SmartMeter.io builds upon JMeter, you can [download it for free](https://www.smartmeter.io/) and it is compatible with JMeter test scripts.